# How do I prevent MacVim from automatically starting Terminal.app on OSX 10.10?

Tags: macvim

I have a laptop with latest OSX 10.10.4 and have tried to install latest MacVim via homebrew, cask and "releases" section in github page.

All works fine, but starting MacVim also opens Terminal.app, which I don't want to be started since I use iTerm. Is it possible to start MacVim without also starting Terminal? Or is there something broken with my clean OSX install?

Temporarily removing my `.vimrc` and `.vim` doesn't help.

Comment: Why not a simple download ?

Comment: @romainl What do you mean by "simple download"?

Comment: Well, you download [the latest snapshot](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases), you install it like any other application and you go back to work.

Comment: @romainl Done exactly that, as stated in question about github "releases" section. Clicking on MacVim icon in "Applications" starts it, but Terminal.app is also started alongside with it.

Comment: It is *possible*, since I have macvim installed and it never does that. I've only ever installed it using homebrew. Did you `brew link macvim` without any issues? What happens if you start macvim in an iterm instance with `mvim -v`?

Comment: @Badger as iTerm instance it starts without spawning terminal. If it doesn't spam terminal for you, that means it's by macbook problem. Can you please post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Badger Thanks to you I have found a problem: it was osascript in my ~/.bashrc that started terminal.